# Expand row from grid to use free space left by a max-height row

Tags: css, css-grid

Given a grid body and these 3 panes:

```
┌───┬───┐
│   │ B │
│ A ├───┤
│   │ C │
└───┴───┘
```

I'm trying to have A and B/C columns to be 50% 50% viewport width ; A to be 100% viewport height, B 60vh and C 40vh.
But also C to be max-height of its `max-content`, and so B to take the remaining place left by C if C's `max-content` is lower than 40vh.
All panes have `overflow-y: auto` and A & B always have scrollable content.

So starting with this

```css
body {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
    grid-template-rows: 60% 40%;
}
.a {
    grid-row: 1 / 3;
}
```

which work appart for the C's *max-height* part, I tried to replace `grid-template-rows`with `60% minmax(40%, max-content)`, or even to use fixed height (say `16em`) instead of *max-content* `minmax(60%, calc(100% - 16em)) minmax(40%, 16em)`, but I'm definitely missing something here.

Comment: Does it have to be done with grid?

Comment: @MinaSoleimanzadeh that's what I'm wondering about: flex (and a container for B and C) would handle this perfectly but… this seems like the kind of case grid was made for and I feel like I'm never gonna use grids otherwise 

Answer (score 0):

[image]

If I understand correctly, It's doable with CSS grid, check the snippet below:

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
#wrapper {
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background: grey;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: minmax(60%, 100%) fit-content(40%);
  overflow: auto;
}
.a {
  background-color: blue;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
}
.b {
  background-color: red;
}
.c {
  background-color: green;
  max-height: 40vh;
  height: max-content;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="a">A</div>
  <div class="b">B</div>
  <div class="c">C</div>
</div>
```

And this is a second snippet with more texts inside the C part with scroll bar:

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
#wrapper {
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background: grey;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: minmax(60%, 100%) fit-content(40%);
  overflow: auto;
}
.a {
  background-color: blue;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
}
.b {
  background-color: red;
}
.c {
  background-color: green;
  max-height: 40vh;
  height: max-content;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="a">A</div>
  <div class="b">B</div>
  <div class="c">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque dignissim felis non felis mollis, ac pellentesque libero tincidunt. Quisque commodo felis vitae mi facilisis placerat eu a dui. Vestibulum ultrices accumsan elit a sollicitudin. Mauris porta, leo sit amet condimentum tincidunt, velit nunc ultricies nibh, imperdiet elementum felis sem sit amet ex. Proin molestie urna sed vulputate ornare. Sed vel pulvinar sem, sit amet condimentum ante. Suspendisse vel tempor tellus. Curabitur sed posuere purus. Vivamus egestas arcu a bibendum tempor.

Nunc ac neque tortor. Sed libero nunc, pulvinar vitae nibh ac, sodales sagittis lacus. Fusce metus dui, luctus sed nisi sed, pulvinar dictum diam. Fusce mauris lacus, efficitur quis tempor eu, viverra ut libero. Pellentesque interdum nunc non vestibulum pulvinar. Mauris aliquam ipsum nec tellus cursus, eget tristique lorem euismod. Donec velit ex, ultrices sit amet pellentesque a, porttitor vel nisi. Fusce facilisis ipsum id urna commodo, egestas sollicitudin mauris porta. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Morbi id rhoncus justo. Praesent efficitur, enim sit amet consequat malesuada, libero sapien dictum est, ac porta arcu velit in quam. Etiam vel arcu et tellus egestas egestas. Sed feugiat ex pretium, mattis eros at, ornare enim. Suspendisse potenti. Vestibulum porttitor eget dui sed placerat. Nam lacus odio, fringilla placerat venenatis eu, fringilla eget nibh.

Nunc sit amet lacinia lorem. Aliquam id lorem lacus. Phasellus auctor aliquet purus, quis pretium lorem tincidunt sit amet. Donec lectus sapien, lacinia eu neque at, feugiat dictum ante. Nam et metus ut leo vestibulum vestibulum. Donec aliquet libero fermentum pellentesque viverra. Nulla fringilla, tellus eget scelerisque tempus, nulla massa vestibulum odio, sit amet malesuada est turpis tincidunt nisl. Sed mauris elit, condimentum ut convallis vitae, ultrices eget elit. Fusce egestas ut ex id convallis. Vivamus accumsan dui nulla, a bibendum nulla pretium et. Duis feugiat sem a nisi feugiat, sed scelerisque elit pellentesque. Pellentesque sollicitudin, lorem egestas consectetur fermentum, lectus est aliquam nulla, et semper odio sapien sit amet ligula. Curabitur consectetur consectetur ex id lacinia. Vivamus eget aliquet ex.</div>
</div>
```

And here the Codepen link : https://codepen.io/BSO__/pen/NWaXZZr

Comment: Brilliant stuff, thanks Ben! Seems to work great on Webkit but not on Firefox. I tried to play with these fit-content / max-content but can't get why Fx doesn't like it (if this is a bug or not).
(And there's also a strange thing happening in Wb when .a has padding: .c is lifted depending on viewport height, till it reaches less than 40vh…)